# Google MAP - Trocar virgula por ponto usando JS nativo

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou usando uma função do google map para retornar a distancia entre CEPs.

```
function callback(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                        kmDistancia = (response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text).split(" ",1);
                        tempoDistancia = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                    }
                }
```

O **kmDistancia**, retorna sempre com virgula `(2,7)`, tenho duas perguntas...

- Como trocar a virgula por ponto, para eu completar o calculo.
- É possível exibir após o ponto 3 digitos.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta operação é bem simples, basta usar o `replace` e o `toFixed`.

```js
var num = '12,3';

console.log(parseFloat(num.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(3));
```

#### Explicação

- O `replace` realiza substituições, neste caso a `,` por `.`.
- Passando o texto substituído para `float` (numero com virgula) é possível usar o método `toFixed`.
- `toFixed(3)` diz que o numero deve ser apresentado com 3 casas decimais.